# Invalid subscript in unity shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Im pretty new to shader coding but I made this one by grouping 2 unlit shaders
When I try to make this shader, which is meant to create an outline and let me interpolate 2 textures unity tells me that there is this error: invalid subscript `vertex´ at line 61

Ive tried some things but i dont get this shader to work properly, if someone knows what do i have to do id be so thankful

```
Shader "Unlit/Combined"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _SecondaryTex("Secondary Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _LerpValue("Transition float", Range(0,1)) = 0.5

        _OutlineColor("Outline color", color) = (0,0,0,1)
        _OutlineWidth("Outline width", Range(1.0,5.0)) = 1.01
    }





        SubShader
        {
            Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque"  "Queue" = "Transparent"}
            LOD 100

            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM

                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                // make fog work
                #pragma multi_compile_fog

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata
                {
                    //float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float3 normal : NORMAL;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                    float4 outvertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float4 pos : POSITION;
                    float3 normal : NORMAL;
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                sampler2D _SecondaryTex;
                float4 _SecondaryTex_ST;
                float _LerpValue;
                float _OutlineWidth;
                float4 _OutlineColor;

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    v.vertex.xyz *= _OutlineWidth;
                    o.outvertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                    UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    // sample the texture
                    fixed4 col = lerp(tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv),tex2D(_SecondaryTex, i.uv), _LerpValue);

                    return col;
                    return _OutlineColor;
                }

                ENDCG
            }


            Pass//Normal render
            {
                ZWrite On

                Material
                {
                    Diffuse[_Color]
                    Ambient[_Color]
                }

                Lighting On

                SetTexture[_MainTex]
                {
                    ConstantColor[_Color]
                }

                SetTexture[_MainTex]
                {
                    Combine previous * primary DOUBLE
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that has a problem is line 61:

```
v.vertex.xyz *= _OutlineWidth;
```

If you look at the type that `v` is declared as, its declared as `appdata`:

```
v2f vert(appdata v)
```

If you look at the definition of `appdata`:

```
struct appdata
{
    //float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};
```

You'll see that it does not have a `vertex` property, only `uv` and `normal`.

So the line that's an issue should be changed to one of those, probably `normal` as you're trying to modify a 3-value property of it (and uv only has `xy`).

```
v.normal.xyz *= _OutlineWidth;
```

Alternatively you can modify `appdata` to have a vertex property by uncommenteing the commented out `vertex`:

```
struct appdata
{
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};
```

Or by removing line 61, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: The problem when I uncomment is that I got 3 errors: output semantic `POSITION` and output semantic `SV_POSITION`     input semantic `SV_POSITION` and input semantic `POSITION`     output semantic `SV_POSITION` and output semantic `POSITION`

Comment: You said three errors and listed 6, but didn't say what lines.

Comment: I listed the 3 of them; they are duplicated system value in: 1st: output semantic POSITION and output semantic SV_POSITION// 2nd: input semantic SV_POSITION and input semantic POSITION// 3rd: output semantic SV_POSITION and output semantic POSITION //  the lines are on the struct v2f at the beggining of the code

Comment: My apologies, I couldn't read them the way you posted them all run together like that. Anyway, comment out lines 45 and 62. You've duplicated the output vertex position (both of these fields are being set to the same value, so you don't need both of them, which is exactly what the error is telling you: "duplicated semantic").